# Excel draggable/ non-draggable cells in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, draggable

So I have a sheet that I need to use basically the same formula over and over again with some cell values static and others dynamic.

```
=IF(NOT(B3=0),IF(Security!B3=1,'UX Deliverables'!B28,0)+IF(Security!B3=2,'UX Deliverables'!C28,0),IF(Security!C3=1,'UX Deliverables'!D28,0)+IF(Security!C3=2,'UX Deliverables'!E28,0)+IF(Security!C3=3,'UX Deliverables'!E28,0))
```

For instance, the next row will have `B3 --> B4` and `C3 --> C4`. All variables from the `UX Deliverables` page will be static references.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out : http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/referencing.php

you can achieve what youre trying to do with $.

`= $A1` will keep the column absolute, but the row relative.

`= A$1` will keep the row absolute but the column relative.

`= $A$1` will keep both absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not seeing the issue but to make part of an address static use "$" so if you want to drag "B3" but make the column static use "$B3" this way when dragged from column A to B the reference will not change from "B3" to "C3" but will stay "B3". However when dragging it from row 1 to row 2 the reference will change from "B3" to "B4".

Hope this helps